# Use Constructor in ASPX Page (No Codebehind)

Tags: asp.net, .net, constructor, code-behind

Can I implement a constructor in an ASPX page without a Codebehind file?

I have a page "test.aspx" and I try to include a constructor:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    public dd_prop_test_aspx() : base() { /* Do stuff */ }
</script>
```

But, the runtime compiler gives me an error:

> CS0111: Type 'ASP.test_aspx' already defines a member called 'test_aspx' with the same parameter types

```
Line 558:        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 559:        public test_aspx() {
Line 560:            string[] dependencies;
```

Can I specify a directive to not generate a constructor automatically (as it appears that the compiler does)? Or, do I have another way of working around this?

In the end, I would like to set variables in the class before Page_PreInit, so if a workaround exists without using constructors, that would work, too.

Comment: Any reason to not just use a code behind?  Why do you need to set values prior to preinit?  Setting values in init is probably the earliest supported lifecycle event you can use.

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman: I want to do some quick testing, and I don't want to have to start/stop my debugger every time I want to change the code.

Comment: Sounds like a bad reason for wanting to do this.  AFAIK, there is no way to do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you cannot redeclare the constructor, you are free to override any method from a `<script runat="server">` tag, as long as you don't override it in the code beside as well. And, you can also add page event handlers (same restrictions apply) like `Page_PreInit`.

As you can use both the page event *and* the override at the same time, you might be able to inject code in advance:

```
<script runat="server">
    void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Response.Write("First?");
    }

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e); // implicitly calls Page_PreInit
        Response.Write("Second!");
    }
</script>
```

So if you are using `Page_PreInit` in your code behind as a page event handler, you can use the override of `OnPreInit` in your .aspx and put your code before the call to `base.OnPreInit(e)`.

If you're overriding `OnPreInit` in your code behind, you can declare a `Page_PreInit` in your .aspx and it depends on where you call `base.OnPreInit(e)` before your code behind logic or after.

In other words: you have full control over when it happens.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely could set data prior to PreInit.